# Does there exist a measure of similarity between matrix distributions estimated by sets of samples

Tags: matrices, statistics, probability-distributions

I want to find a measure of similarity (or distance) between **matrix distributions** estimated by sets of matrices, but after some searching, all I could find was measures of similarity between multivariate distributions.

I know that some matrix distributions are equal to their multivariate counterparts (like matrix normal can be converted to multivariate normal), and we can do the similarity check under the multivariate situation. But is there any method that can be directly applied to matrix distribution?

Specifically, I want to know

1. Under the assumption that two sets of matrices obey two different matrix normal distribution, is there any method that measures the similarity between these two distribution?
2. Or more generally, without any assumptions about the distribution, how can I measure the similarity between the distributions of these two sets of samples?